# Does the Registry class in the Microsoft.Win32.Registry package get type-forwarded to the mscorlib.dll when used in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-standard

I have a **.NET Standard 2.0** library with a dependency on [the Microsoft.Win32.Registry package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/).  Here's a simple class:

```
namespace ClassLibrary4
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var lm = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
        }
    }
}
```

When I reference my assembly from a **.NET Framework 4.7.2** application, I would have thought that the `Registry` class from the package dependency in my **.NET Standard** class library would be type-forwarded to the `Registry` class defined in the **.NET Framework** BCL, within the mscorlib.dll.  However, when I "Go to Definition" in Visual Studio, here's the top of what's generated from metadata:

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 
// C:\Users\rapperson\.nuget\packages\microsoft.win32.registry\4.7.0\ref\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
#endregion
```

Notice that it's the **.NET Standard** version of the DLL rather than mscorlib.dll.  I can confirm that this is the same assembly my code is using because a `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll` is put in the output folder of my .NET Framework project, and it has the same version and public key token:

[image]

My understanding of **.NET Standard** is that it's just a *specification* that .NET platforms (e.g. .NET Framework, .NET Core, etc.) must adhere to.  So why isn't my **.NET Framework** application using its own `Registry` class (from mscorlib.dll)?

Here's my .NET Framework code, though it's largely irrelevant:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new ClassLibrary4.Class1();
            c.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the library reference via NuGet package to the console application or via the Project Menu->Add reference?  [.NET implementation support - footnote #2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) implies using NuGet is the proper way.  When I use NuGet  all works fine, but when I directly reference the library I see the issue you are having.  If needed see: [Creating and using a local NuGet package repository](https://medium.com/@churi.vibhav/creating-and-using-a-local-nuget-package-repository-9f19475d6af8).

Comment: @TnTinMn I used the NuGet method.  Also my framework project is 4.7.2 so that footnote doesn't apply (it suggests updating _to_ 4.7.2).  Can you elaborate on "all works fine"?  What are you seeing happen?

Comment: You've only been looking at reference assemblies, but the type forwarding occurs at runtime.  Add Console.WriteLine(typeof(Microsoft.Win32.Registry).Assembly.Location); to Test() to see it in action.

Comment: `elaborate on "all works fine"` = All registry types from the library assembly pointed to the expected .Net Framework mscorlib assembly as is hoped for.  The net standard library holds a reference to the external "Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" and as such when you compile the console application a "Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" is placed in the output as you have seen.

Comment: If you inspect the outputted  Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll with your favorite decompiler, you should see that it references mscorlib, and holds no code for the expected types; rather it primarily comprises a bunch of [TypeForwardedToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute?view=netframework-4.8)s like `[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(RegistryKey))]`.  Those attributes are what does the _hand waving magic_ that make it work.  If those attributes do not exist, then something wonky happened.